# Extract contents of folder in tar file

Tags: python, tar

I am trying to extract a tar file in python, and was wondering if I could extract the contents of a folder in a tar file.
For example:

tar_files.tar.gz

- tar_files

  - test.txt
  - test2.txt
  - mydir

    - test3.txt
  - mydir2

    - test4.txt

I want to extract it to `mydirectory`, like so:

- mydirectory

  - test.txt
  - test2.txt
  - mydir

    - test3.txt
  - mydir2

    - test4.txt

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Have you looked into the `tarfile` module?

Comment: I am using the `tarfile` module. However, when I try extracting the files, it extracts with the `tar_files` directory under `mydirectory`. Instead, I want the contents of `tar_files`, inside `mydirectory`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick-and-dirty way to do this:

```
import os
import sys

#Name of tarfile (without the .tar.gz extension)
file_name = "tarfile"

#Target directory
target_dir = "mydirectory"


#Extract the tar file
os.system("tar -xf " + file_name + ".tar.gz")

#Move the tar files into your target folder
os.system("mv " + file_name + " " + target_dir)
```

Although the `os.system` calls may not be very best practice, it gets the job done quick.

Alternatively you could look into the `tarfile` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html